# Baby Rudin Problem 6.2: Is continuity a necessary condition?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Problem: Suppose $f \geq 0$, f is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Assume not. Then, there exists a $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) > 0$. My proof idea is to choose any partition P, which means that there exists an $x_i \in P$ such that $x_{i-1} \leq c \leq x_i$. From Rudin's definition, $M_i = \sup f(x) > 0$ over that interval. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta x_i = U(P, f) > 0$.

This implies that $\overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \: dx = \inf U(P, f) > 0$ as the chosen partition was arbitrary. However, $\int_a^b f(x) \: dx > 0$, a contradiction.

Rudin assumes that $f$ is continuous; however, I was questioning if it's a necessary condition to prove the problem or have I misinterpreted the definition of a Riemann integral?

Comment: You only showed $\inf U(P,f)\ge 0$. You need to use continuity to find $c>0$ such that $U(P,f)>c$ for every partition $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, continuity is essential. Otherwise consider the following situation: fix an $a\in [0,1]$ and let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be defined as
\begin{align}
f(x):= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x\neq a$} \\
1 & \text{if $x=a$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $f\geq 0$, is Riemann-integrable with $\int_0^1f = 0$, but $f$ is not the zero function.

The point is that the function $f$ here is zero almost everywhere (both in the intuitive, and also in a technical sense), and integration doesn't really care about what happens on such "negligibly small" sets. More generally, take the zero function on an interval $[a,b]$, and modify it at finitely many points. The resulting function is still Riemann-integrable, has zero integral, but clearly it is no longer the zero-function.

---

By the way, your proof as stated isn't accurate. All you showed is that "for every partition $P$, $U(P,f)>0$". From this statement alone, it DOES NOT follow that $\inf U(P,f) > 0$; the infimum of a set of strictly positive numbers could very well be $0$. What you need to do is show that there exists a $\lambda>0$, such that for every partition $P$, $U(P,f)\geq \lambda$. Then, from this it will follow that $\inf U(P,f) \geq \lambda > 0$, and hence you obtain the desired contradiction.

To fix the proof (assume throughout that $a<b$), what you could do is say that since $f$ is continuous at $c$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in [a,b]$ with $|x-c|\leq \delta$, we have $f(x) \geq \frac{f(c)}{2} > 0$. Now, fix a point $t\in [a,b]$ such that $|t-c| = \delta$. Then, given any partition $P$, we can refine it to get a partition $P' = P\cup \{c, t\}$. Then,
\begin{align}
U(P,f) \geq U(P',f) \geq \frac{f(c)}{2}|t-c| = \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2}\delta \cdot f(c)}_{:= \lambda} > 0
\end{align}
From this, it follows that $\inf U(P,f) \geq \lambda > 0$, and hence we have a contradiction.

If you want to get some more practice, I suggest you write up an proof using lower sums $L(P,f)$, and the supremum $\sup L(P,f)$, and show that this is strictly positive.